# how to add class reference in asp.net

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio

I am creating basic project which includes layers. One is bussiness layer another one is Data layer. And my front end(default page). I have created 2 classes for BL and DL. Please help me how to add that class in my project.

Comment: Have you added a reference to your project using the "Add Reference" button on the context menu?

Answer (score 1):

The most common method is to build these classes as **DLL** and then **add a reference** to these dll in your project.

For adding reference in your solution explorer right click the project and choose Add Reference link and then browse the DLL and choose it.

Answer (score 1):

In your solution explorer window you'll find a References folder. Right click it, **Add Reference**, then from the Browse tab you can browse to your dlls and add them.

Alternately you can do it from Project -> Add References.

If they are not compiled and are in source code format you could right click your project and **Add Existing Item** and then add your classes (or Project -> Add Existing Item).

Answer (score 0):

At solution explorer, right click to your References, select your assembly you want to reference.

After that, add the namespace reference to your page like that :

```
using my.BusinessLayer;
```